# R function for comparing data within a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

```
> head(peaks)
       m.z Height    RT
1  84.9594 358909 0.219
2 214.9169 111512 0.223
3  56.9418 168197 0.261
4 201.8865  26736 0.352
5 122.9683  20625 0.465
6  84.9594 343573 0.854
```

I have a dataframe, where I want to search the m.z column for any pairs that differ between 4 and 6. The column is over 700 datapoints long, so it is not an option to search for pairs for each datapoint seperately. Is there a function or package which makes it possible to analyze the whole column for pairs at once?

I only discovered functions for the comparison of two dataframes

Comment: Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  In the future, it will be easier to get help if you can also provide your data in a way that we can copy easily.  In your example here, you could do `dput(peaks)` and then copy the result into your question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to find any pairs of elements in the `m.z` column whose value differs by between 4 and 6. You can use `dist` to get such pairwise comparisons:

```r
m <- as.matrix(dist(peaks$m.z, diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE))

m
#>          1        2        3        4        5        6
#> 1   0.0000 129.9575  28.0176 116.9271  38.0089   0.0000
#> 2 129.9575   0.0000 157.9751  13.0304  91.9486 129.9575
#> 3  28.0176 157.9751   0.0000 144.9447  66.0265  28.0176
#> 4 116.9271  13.0304 144.9447   0.0000  78.9182 116.9271
#> 5  38.0089  91.9486  66.0265  78.9182   0.0000  38.0089
#> 6   0.0000 129.9575  28.0176 116.9271  38.0089   0.0000
```

To find which distances are between 4 and 6, we would do:

```
which(m > 4 & m < 6, arr.ind = TRUE)
#> row  col
```

This means that none of the values in your sample are between 4 and 6 units apart. If such a pair did exist, you will get a 2-column array where each row represents a pair meeting your criteria.

We can see this by changing the first element of `m.z` to 61, so that it is between 4 and 6 away from the value in the 3rd row of your data frame:

```r
peaks$m.z[1] <- 61

m <- as.matrix(dist(peaks$m.z, diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE))

which(m > 4 & m < 6, arr.ind = TRUE)
#>   row col
#> 3   3   1
#> 1   1   3
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach yields a data frame that matches the pairings on indices (the row number). It's a fair bit slower than Allan's solution, but may be worth it if you prefer the resulting structure over the matrix (purely a stylistic matter). I've added a row of data to your example that illustrates what it looks like when pairings exist.

```
peaks <- data.frame(m.z = c(84.9594, 214.9169, 56.9418, 201.8865, 122.9683, 84.9594, 89.000), 
                    Height = c(358909, 111512, 168197, 26736, 20625, 343573, 343577), 
                    RT = c(0.219, 0.223, 0.261, 0.352, 0.465, 0.854, 0.900))

# Assign an index to each row
peaks$index <- seq_len(nrow(peaks))

# For each row, get the pairwise differences with all other rows
# Make an logical value indicating if the difference is between 4 and 6
# It also adds a 'reference index' which indicates which row is being compared to the others
peaks_compare <- 
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(peaks)), 
         function(i){
           diff <- abs(peaks$m.z[i] - peaks$m.z) 
           peaks$ref_index <- rep(i, nrow(peaks))
           peaks$in_range <- diff >= 4 & diff <= 6
           peaks
         })

# put all the data frames together and filter down to just those where
# the difference is in the target range.
peaks_compare <- do.call("rbind", peaks_compare)
peaks_compare <- peaks_compare[peaks_compare$in_range, ]

# Order the data frame 
peaks_compare <- peaks_compare[order(peaks_compare$ref_index, 
                                     peaks_compare$index), ]

peaks_compare
#>        m.z Height    RT index ref_index in_range
#> 7  89.0000 343577 0.900     7         1     TRUE
#> 42 89.0000 343577 0.900     7         6     TRUE
#> 43 84.9594 358909 0.219     1         7     TRUE
#> 48 84.9594 343573 0.854     6         7     TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what i wanted. In the next step i would like to filter the obtained dataframe (peaks_compare) for value differences in the RT column for the single groups of m.z that are in range. That means the filter for RT values should be applied for the single ref_index groups.